# PHPUnit Data Provider Argument Count Error

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have just started using `PHPUnit`. So far, everything is going perfect except the `Data Provider` issue.

The problem is when I run test, it passes. But if I run it once again, it fails with the following error:

```
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function ValidationTest::testValidateType(), 0 passed and at least 3 expected
```

If I make any changes to the data provider function (i.e. change the data to be returned, provider function name etc.) and re-run, it passes for once and fails with the above error for all consecutive test runs.

I am using the latest version of PHPUnit (updated an hour ago). Unfortunately I did not find any specific solution anywhere. So, I am really worried, am I doing very silly mistake(s)?

Not sure, but does PHPUnit use any caching mechanism to cache provider data? If yes, then is there any way to clean it (maybe using `setUp` or `tearDown`)?

Look forward to seeing expert opinions. Thanks in advance. :-)

---

**The following code work once (pass once):**

```
/**
 * @covers Validation
 * @coversDefaultClass Validation
 */
class ValidationTest extends TestCase {

    protected $validation;


    protected function setUp() {
        $this->validation = new Validation();
    }


    /**
     * @covers ::validateType
     * @dataProvider validateTypeProdiver
     */
    public function testValidateType($assertion, $argument, $type) {
        $result = $this->validation->validateType($argument, $type);

        switch ($assertion) {
            case 'True':
                $this->assertTrue($result);
                break;
        }
    }


    public function validateTypeProdiver() {
        return [
            ['True', 'file.txt', 'str']
       ];
    }
}
```

---

**The following code always work (passes everytime):**

```
/**
 * @covers Validation
 * @coversDefaultClass Validation
 */
class ValidationTest extends TestCase {

    protected $validation;


    protected function setUp() {
        $this->validation = new Validation();
    }


    /**
     * @covers ::validateType
     */
    public function testValidateType() {
        foreach ($this->validateTypeProdiver() as $args) {
            $result = call_user_func_array([$this->validation, 'validateType'], array_slice($args, 1));

            switch ($args[0]) {
                case 'True':
                    $this->assertTrue($result);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    public function validateTypeProdiver() {
        return [
            ['True', 'file.txt', 'str']
       ];
    }
}
```

**Here is the configuration:**

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" colors="true" verbose="true" beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="ProjectX Unit Test">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/ProjectX</directory>
            <exclude>tests/ProjectX/assets</exclude>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">src/ProjectX</directory>
            <exclude>src/ProjectX/nodejs-commands</exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Do you pass the 3 mandatory arguments to the function? Also, can you please provide your code?

Comment: Yes, and that's why it passes once. If you investigate the error message you will see it says `0 passed`, means it does not pass any of the provided arguments. :-(

Comment: I test your code and seems work fine. Check the error is i some other place.

Comment: Same thing is happening for all of my taste cases when use `Data Provider`. Otherwise they work fine. :-(

Comment: I found the note underneath the `Data Providers` documentation: "All data providers are executed before both the call to the `setUpBeforeClass` static method and the first call to the `setUp` method. Because of that you can't access any variables you create there from within a data provider. This is required in order for PHPUnit to be able to compute the total number of tests." Any hints?

Comment: 1. What IDE do you use? 2. How exactly do you run tests? (copy-paste us the command)

Comment: I use NetBeans for PHP on Windows. The command line also results the same. I use xml configuration which one I have added to the question. :)

Comment: Guys, thanks for your cordial concerns, but I have came around with my own solution which replaces the `Data Provider` feature, but a better way. I think I will use it for all of my future implementations. But if the issue could be resolved, it would be better for them who faces / will face the same issue. :)

Comment: If nobody else can reproduce the inconsistent behavior, and the only thing you did not post is the code for the Validation class itself, then that could be where the inconsistent behavior lies.

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit uses the `@dataProvider` annotation to configure the data provider method.
If you use OPcache, you have to ensure also documentation comments will be stored in cache.

Look for `opcache.save_comments=On` in your `php.ini`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.save-comments

Answer (score -1):

It's quite old question but I want to leave note. The solution is never use same test instance for multiple because every test needs different dependency.

```
/**
 * @covers Validation
 * @coversDefaultClass Validation
 */
class ValidationTest extends TestCase {
    /**
     * @covers ::validateType
     * @dataProvider validateTypeProdiver
     */
    public function testValidateType($assertion, $argument, $type) {
        $classUnderTest = new Validation();
        $result = $classUnderTest->validateType($argument, $type);

        switch ($assertion) {
            case 'True':
                $this->assertTrue($result);
                break;
        }
    }

    public function validateTypeProdiver() {
        return [
            ['True', 'file.txt', 'str']
       ];
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely doesn't fix the problem described above.